# Calling dynamic component in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

I am new in react JS. I am calling a react component from a HTML string which is coming from another javascript class. But the component is not rendering on the screen.

```
class Form extends Component {
   render() {
       var markup = '<Sections />';
       return (<div className="content" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: markup}}></div>);
   }

}

class Sections extends Component{
   render(){
      return (<div className='row'>Row1</div>);
   } 
}
```

Please help me where am i going wrong.
I think the reactjs is not recognizing the sections component as it is coming from the string. Is there any way, we can manually compile the jsx.

Comment: Yes I have defined Section as a component. I generate the JSX as string dynamically and return it in the render method. React cannot resolve it to a Section Component and hence does not render the Section component

Comment: I have tried it but it is not displaying

Comment: in the HTML string
if i am giving "<Sections />", then it is giving Uncaught Invariant Violation: Invalid tag.
If i am giving only "Sections", then it is creating Section component but not invoking the predefined component

Comment: It'd help a lot if you post the code for `t.getComponent`.

Comment: What is `singleSection`? What is `Builder()`? I'm not sure this example is [minimal, complete, and verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: t.getComponent returns only a html string '<Sections />' which i have mentioned above. The main idea is that i am having a components name in html string which i have to rendered it on the UI using react component

Comment: I have updated the code

Comment: Can you expand on your case? Why can't your JS class return something other than string? What's the use case?

Comment: why not just do return (<div className="content”><Sections /></div>)

Answer (score 0):

Remember that JSX isn't the same as HTML. When you write something like `<Sections />` you are in fact writing `React.createElement(Sections, null)`.

If you have `"<Sections />"` as a string and you want to resolve it to a call to `React.createElement` then you need to parse it as JSX. However, this happens at compile-time (not run-time) which would prevent you from using dynamic components.

If you want to work with a dynamic component, then your builder method **must** return a component class or a component instance.

```
function getDynamicComponent() {
  return Sections;
}
function render() {
  const Component = getDynamicComponent();
  return <Component />;
}

// or

function getDynamicComponentInstance() {
  return <Sections />;
}
function render() {
  const component = getDynamicComponentInstance();
  return component;
}
```

The only way to infer the correct component from `"<Sections />"` is to parse it manually and use `eval` to resolve the name to the appropriate variable. Parsing JSX is non-trivial and using `eval` is likely to open you up to a whole class of security vulnerabilities.

Unless your dynamic component name is coming from over the network, or from inside a separate worker, there's no reason why the function which returns your dynamic component can't be written like the example above.

Comment: Dan,
I have a list of components name in t.getComponent() method which will give me the name in html string which i have to rendered it on the UI.

Comment: If you are returning a string as JSX then you're going to have a difficult time. The best option would be to rewrite your function to return actual JSX instead.